# How to centre ionic-icon in Ionic app when ion-text-centre is not working?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to centre an ***ion-icon*** in my Ionic app, I tried to use the *ion-text-center* class I got from the ionic documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities), but it's not rendering any change.

Here is my code:

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">

    <ion-toolbar color="danger">
        <ion-title>
          Feedly
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">


    <ion-item class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-icon name="logo-rss" class="logo" color="light"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item> 

</ion-content>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, & how to resovle this?

Comment: you should looking into using ion-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col size="12" text-center>
            <ion-item>
             <ion-icon name="logo-rss"></ion-icon>
            </ion-item>
           </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
```

Basically you want to use icon grid to control layout and placement within col and rows.